# Zoom / Scale in different device width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website with is not responsive, I can do it responsive with media-queries. But it will be huge task.... I want a short-cut process to zoom / scale my website to fit with device width. Please help me anyone

Comment: use some framwork like FOundation or Bootstarp. or do css coding in %. this can help u till some extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to use this meta tag to get the solution.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">
```

Thank You ALL. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media viewport to set the content specifications.

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.00, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, minimum-scale=1.00, maximum-scale=1.00, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: @ Rachelle. Thanks for comment. I aleady used it... but not working.... do you have any specific jquery function to scale fullsite

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommand using a grid system which is provided by some frameworks such as bootstrap . and believe it will make the job too much easier for you . here is a link from the bootstrap official website which will explain everything for you . try to resize the browser window to notice the difference.